# Can't open RN app either Android or iOS when running packager on 8082

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've seen this question being asked multiple times, but no answer seemed to fix my issue (some of the answers are probably outdated now)

I have the port 8081 being used by a process that I cannot kill. So I had to do:

`react-native start --port 8082`

So far so good.

## Issue on iOS

When I execute `react-native run-ios` I get the following error in the terminal `Port 8081 already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly.`. I've seen multiple answers saying to change something in the AppDelegate.m, but I don't have anything stating the port in that file.

## Issue on Android

When I execute `react-native run-android` I get the following error in the emulator:
`Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.`

## My dependencies

```
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "^0.47.0",
"react-native-camera-roll-picker": "^1.2.0",
"react-native-elements": "^0.16.0",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.2.5",
"react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.3.1",
"react-native-maps": "^0.16.2",
"react-native-nav": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
```

Am I missing any step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On Android Device:

Did you try

```
adb forward tcp:8082 tcp:8082
```

If this did not work, you can open the menu in emulator and open "dev Settings", then go to "Debug server Host & port for device", asssign your computer an ip and write something like "yourIp:Port", like:

```
192.168.0.1:8081
```

Then it should be all good to go.

If these two methods did not work, make sure you disable "Debug JS remotely". and try npm install one more time. Please check these and if did not work tell us more about your react-native version and packages you used (probably "Realm").

2. On IOS Device

Open the file RCTWebSocketExecutor.m and change "localhost" to the IP address of your computer, then select "Debug JS Remotely" from the Developer Menu.

Comment: Changing the ip:port in the `Debug server Host & port for device` fixed the issue for Android. Still have the issue for iOS

Comment: On iOS devices, open the file RCTWebSocketExecutor.m and change "localhost" to the IP address of your computer, then select "Debug JS Remotely" from the Developer Menu.

Comment: where can I get Debug server host & port option in android emulator

Comment: press ctrl+M on emulator, or shake your phone on real android device